# Problems with installing libraries with pip

Tags: python, pip

I am having a problem when I run the command 'pip install -r requirements.txt'.  And it results in an error

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.7 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.7; 0.8 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.7
```

I have no idea why this could happen. Please help me!

Comment: It's seems that one (or more) package requires python 3.6 to 3.7

Which version have you ?

Please add all the error, it should have which package need this python version

Comment: 1)  ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.7 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.7; 0.8 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.7


2)  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement payme-pkg==2.6.3 (from versions: 2.6.5)


3)  ERROR: No matching distribution found for payme-pkg==2.6.3

Comment: I am using python 3.11.2

Answer (score 0):

### First error

- `Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.7 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.7; 0.8 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.7`

This package version (0.7 / 0,8) requires python 3.6 to 3.7

But We do not have the name of the package which requires this.
Are you sure you have put all the error message ?

### Second error

- `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement payme-pkg==2.6.3 (from versions: 2.6.5)`: tell you that no package 2.6.3 is available, but 2.6.5 is available

#### First solution - Better solution

Update your dependencies file (requirements.txt) with the version of the package payme-pgk==2.6.5

*If you need help, add your requirements.txt content to show us*

#### Second solution

You can do `pip install payme-pgk`